# r one sided geom_quasirandom

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am interested in plotting the distribution of some continuous variables by groups using the `geom_quasirandom()` function.

I would like to know how do plot only one side, for example only points on the right side rather than on both sides.

```
ggplot(iris,aes(Species, Sepal.Length)) + geom_quasirandom()
```

I am interested in a plot like this. I am not interested in solutions based on `geom_beeswarm` because I have a lot of datapoints and `geom_beeswarm` just creates a crowded mess for my dataset. So any solution specific to `geom_quasirandom()` will be helpful. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach, pulling the guts out of a beeswarm and using dplyr to adjust these manually, and adding the Species labels back manually.

```
ggplot_build(ggplot(iris,aes(Species, Sepal.Length)) + 
  geom_quasirandom()) -> a

a$data[[1]] %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(x_adj = group + abs(x - median(x))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  
  ggplot(aes(x_adj, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:3, labels = unique(iris$Species))
```

...or a hack to keep the automatic labeling by using an invisible layer:

```
...
ggplot(aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0) +
  geom_point(aes(x = x_adj))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's funny, the first example below is actually in the [README](https://github.com/eclarke/ggbeeswarm) for {ggbeeswarm} but it doesn't seem to work with my versions of R and the package.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggbeeswarm)

# doesn't look asymetric as shown in the vingette
ggplot(iris,aes(Species, Sepal.Length)) + geom_beeswarm(side = 1L) 
#> Warning: Ignoring unknown parameters: side
```

[image]

However using the [{see}](https://easystats.github.io/see/index.html) package you can get pretty close to what I think you're asking for.

```r
library(see)
# this works if you turn off the violin half
ggplot(iris,aes(Species, Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_violindot(fill = NA, color = NA, color_dots = "black", size_dots = 1, fill_dots = "black")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>